# How is String.Length implemented in C#?

Tags: c#

As per my understanding, there is no null-termination at the end of a C# string. So how does Length get to know how many characters a string have?

Thanks,
Gyan

Answer (score 16):

It's stored in a field within the object.

As it happens, strings *are* null-terminated internally in the current implementation of .NET, but that's only for the sake of interop, so that code which *does* expect null-terminated strings can be given the same chunk of memory to work with.

Note that having it in a field is a good idea in terms of performance anyway - it makes finding the length an O(1) operation instead of O(N).

Comment: Random historical aside: The C convention was largely a convenience so you could pass the pointer to the string directly and not have to worry about a structure with length included (which also meant keeping the length in sync when modifying the buffer.)  Some Pascal implementations (such as Delphi) took a slightly hackier approach and stored the string length at the *(ptr-4) location; it was your job to update this if you manually modified the buffer.  Since .NET Strings are immutable, this nicely side-steps the synchronization issue (as long as you don't rudely poke the backing memory.)